# PySpark problem, failure to run program java

Tags: pyspark

So I was getting started with Scala, however im encountering problems that seem to be related to my environmental variable JAVA_HOME. The weird part is the code works perfectly when i load a dataframe but doesn't work when i create a new data set.

I have two different notebooks, that contain code but the code of interest is as simple as this:

```
 # Aqui hacemos lo mismo añadiendo la aplicación
spark2 = (SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .config('spark.ui.port','4050')
        .getOrCreate())

# Reading csv into a variable to store it
datos = spark2.read.csv('housing.csv',header = True).show()
```

The above code works, showing me the loaded dataset. But this one crashes:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])

df.show()
```

Error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (192.168.1.13 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.

Comment: what is the output of the command: `update-alternatives --config java` if you dont see anything, you might need to install java or set java path correctly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a Linux-type command, right? I am working at the moment with a Windows one. What's the code intended to do? So I can do a similar thing in Windows. Update Java? The Java I have installed is JDK 1.8.0_202 @vagitus

Comment: apparently, spark cannot find java. Please check how to setup java path for windows